# Meaning of ampersand (&) in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I recently came across this and was wondering what `&django` means

```
version: '2'

services:
  django: &django
```

I can't see anything in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) related to this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

These are a YAML feature called anchors, and are not particular to Docker Compose. I would suggest you have a look at below URL for more details

https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/

Follow the section `EXTRA YAML FEATURES`

> YAML also has a handy feature called 'anchors', which let you easily duplicate
>   content across your document. Both of these keys will have the same value:
>
> anchored_content: **&anchor_name** This string will appear as the value of two keys.
>   other_anchor: ***anchor_name**

#### Anchors can be used to duplicate/inherit properties

```
base: &base
    name: Everyone has same name

foo: &foo
    <<: *base
    age: 10

bar: &bar
    <<: *base
    age: 20
```

Answer (score 38):

To complement Tarun's answer, `&` identifies an anchor and `*` is an alias referring back to the anchor. It is described as the following in the [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2765878):

> In the representation graph, a node may appear in more than one
>   collection. When serializing such data, the first occurrence of the
>   node is identified by an anchor. Each subsequent occurrence is
>   serialized as an alias node which refers back to this anchor.

**Sidenote:**

For those who want to start using anchors in your docker-compose files, there is more powerful way to make re-usable anchors by using [docker-compose YAML extension fields](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/5140).

```
version: "3.4"

# x-docker-data is an extension and when docker-compose
# parses the YAML, it will not do anything with it

x-docker-data: &docker-file-info
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile

services:
  some_service_a:
    <<: *docker-file-info
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:9090
  some_service_b:
    <<: *docker-file-info
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:9595
```

Comment: It could be worth emphasizing that it doesn't have to be called `x-docker-data`. "Any top-level key which starts with x- will be ignored by compose."