# Consul configuration in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, consul

I'm trying to setup a consul cluster locally using docker-compose, and my source of inspiration (this is my first interaction with consul), is this [consul.yml](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/master/demo/docker-compose-cluster/docker-compose.yml). This configuration contains some syntax that I'm seeing for the first time.

I'm figuring that this

```
consul-agent-1: &consul-agent
    image: consul:latest
```

serves as some kind of base (like in inheritance) ?

and this part is the derived ? I don't know how to call it

```
consul-server-bootstrap:
    <<: *consul-agent
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong about this assumption.

But what I find very strange is this part in ***consul-agent-1***

```
command: "agent -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"
```

It does 'something' (I'm not sure what exactly) with ***consul-server-bootstrap*** service.

I don't understand it, I mean if I'm correct that ***consul-agent-1*** serves as some base template for other services, and if ***consul-server-bootstrap*** uses the template, isn't this a circular reference ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `&consul-agent` and `<<: *consul-agent` are features of YAML files that allow to
re-use some parts by merging them with "base dictionary" (as mentioned [by Blake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65317108/6147064)). Here are a couple of additional articles
that showcase DRY for YAML files,
[one](https://medium.com/@kinghuang/docker-compose-anchors-aliases-extensions-a1e4105d70bd)
and
[two](https://blog.betomorrow.com/yaml-tips-and-tricks-for-concourse-ci-35a3b577a239).

However, in this part

```yaml
command: "agent -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"
```

`consul-server-bootstrap` has nothing to do with YAML anchors that used to
"inherit/merge directories". Instead, it is related to some form of [service
discovery](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) intrinsic to docker compose, i.e.
each container gets assigned certain hostname that can be referenced in other parts of
docker compose files or within each service configuration for communication between
services/containers.

When you run

```
docker-compose up
```

there will be 3 containers that run consul agent in "client" mode and 3 containers that
run it in ["server" mode](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_server). Consul
agents that run on a backend (or inside a container) in "client" mode report to consul
servers.

> A server node takes on the additional responsibility of being part of the
> consensus quorum. These nodes take part in Raft and provide strong consistency and
> availability in the case of failure

So `consul-server-1`, `consul-server-2` and `consul-server-bootstrap` carry the same
functions, where the latter just waits until the [specified number of
servers](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_bootstrap_expect) are
available, i.e. `-bootstrap-expect 3`, and then bootstraps the consul cluster.

See official docs for more information about [consul
agent](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent) and its'
[configuration](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options).

#### TLDR;

Note, that without YAML anchors them here is how demo setup of Consul with
[`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/blob/8d8d269cac/demo/docker-compose-cluster/docker-compose.yml)
would look like:

```yaml
version: '3'
)
services:
  consul-agent-1:
    image: consul:latest
    networks:
      - consul-demo
    command: "agent -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"

  consul-agent-2:
    # Complete copy of 'consul-agent-1'
    image: consul:latest
    networks:
      - consul-demo
    command: "agent -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"

  consul-agent-3:
    # Complete copy of 'consul-agent-1'
    image: consul:latest
    networks:
      - consul-demo
    command: "agent -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"

  consul-server-1:
    # Uses only image and networks from 'consul-agent-1'
    # while 'command' is overwritten
    image: consul:latest
    networks:
      - consul-demo
    command: "agent -server -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"

  consul-server-2:
    # Complete copy of 'consul-server-1'
    image: consul:latest
    networks:
      - consul-demo
    command: "agent -server -retry-join consul-server-bootstrap -client 0.0.0.0"

  consul-server-bootstrap:
    # Uses only image and networks from 'consul-agent-1'
    # while 'command' is overwritten and 'ports' are defined
    image: consul:latest
    networks:
      - consul-demo
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8600:8600"
      - "8600:8600/udp"
    command: "agent -server -bootstrap-expect 3 -ui -client 0.0.0.0"

networks:
  consul-demo:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using a feature of YAML called anchors and merge keys to template / re-use some of the configuration in the compose file. See this StackOverflow answer for more info.

[Meaning of ampersand (&) in docker-compose.yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805380/meaning-of-ampersand-in-docker-compose-yml-file)